# How is SQP (Sequential Quadratic Programming) equivalent to Newton's method for KKT (Karush-Kuhn-Tucker) problems?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson, karush-kuhn-tucker

The title speaks for itself. Basically, SQP is equivalent to Newton's method for KKT.

**I need to prove this statement**. However, I do not know how to do this. I don't  even know how to start this. How do you prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQP describes a class of algorithms, presumably you have one in mind?

Comment: I am using the description of the algorithm basics on the Wikipedia's page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming#Algorithm_basics

Comment: The basic step in SQP is, not surprisingly, a (constrained) QP, Newton's method is unconstrained. How can they be equivalent?